# Apache rotatelogs command is failing and apache doesnt restart

Tags: apache-2.2, logrotate, xampp

I have a command to implement rotatelogs for access logs of apache, but when I am trying to restart my apache server, it doesnt start and throws me an error in error.log as:

```
The parameter is incorrect.  : AH00104: unable to start piped log program 'C:/xampp/apache/bin/rotatelogs C:/xampp/apache/logs/access-%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 3M'
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

The snippet which I am using for rotate log is :

```
CustomLog "|C:/xampp/apache/bin/rotatelogs C:/xampp/apache/logs/access-%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 3M" common
```

**NOTE: I am accessing the server setup through XAMPP, and I am using Windows 7**

I am sure I am putting some wrong rotatelog command, which I followed from [here](https://xp-rience.blogspot.in/2010/07/using-rotatelogs-in-apache-xampp.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten the "-l", as I see on page http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=1353

```
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l D:/Apache2.2/logs/access.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400" common
```

This is what I've got working with XAMPP on Windows 7:

```
CustomLog "|c:/ghp/xampp/apache/bin/rotatelogs.exe c:/temp/httpd_access.log%Y%m%d%H%M 1M" combined
```

Comment: I tried that as well.. didnt work

Comment: In every example I find, people are using "rotatelogs.exe"  (without "-l").  That's not what your snippet shows.  The example you followed specifies a number of times "XAMPP (on linux)".

Comment: I got it working with .exe extension....

Comment: You'd think Apache could have guessed that bit by itself.